# Contract "ItemMint" should be marked as abstract

Tags: ethereum, solidity, abstract, contract

**code**

> trying to create contract using KIP37 as base contract. its works fine for the previous version of @klaytn/contracts - 0.9.0, but it is not working for @klaytn/contracts - 1.0.0

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlincesed
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@klaytn/contracts/contracts/KIP/token/KIP37/KIP37.sol";
// this line showing error "Contract ItemMint should be abstract
contract ItemMint is KIP37 {
    string public name;

    constructor(string memory _name) {
        name = _name;
    }

    function mint(address to) public pure returns (bool) {
        require(msg.sender == to , "your are authorized");
        return true;
    }
}
```

*using npm i @klaytn/contracts - 1.0.0*

Comment: As a heads up, you should probably include any error message that is stopping you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The parent [KIP37](https://github.com/klaytn/klaytn-contracts/blob/master/contracts/KIP/token/KIP37/KIP37.sol) contract defines a constructor that takes one argument - a string named `uri_`, so you need to invoke the parent constructor as well.

```
constructor(string memory _name, string memory uri_) KIP37(uri_) {
    name = _name;
}
```